# How to check "Show as expanded" by default on the Add menu item page

Tags: 8, forms, navigation

I need the 'Show as Expanded' checkbox on the Add menu item page to be selected by default.

I created a module, 'expand_menu_items', and tried a hook_form_alter function to get the id, apparently it's 'menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form'.

I know I'm looking for #default_value, there are a couple and tried setting them to 'TRUE' but it's not having an effect on the page (xdebug shows the value as true). What could I be doing wrong?

Similar questions exist here:

- [Drupal 8 Menu always show as expanded](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198753/drupal-8-menu-always-show-as-expanded) - Though I may use the sql query to fix existing menu items, I'm more concerned with new menu items.
- [How to set the default "Show as expanded" to true in a custom menu item](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200225/how-to-set-the-default-show-as-expanded-to-true-in-a-custom-menu-item) - This seemed promising, although in this case, all the menu items were added by end users.

Here's the function code:

```
function expand_menu_items_form_alter($form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'menu_link_content_menu_link_content_form') {
    // $form['expanded']['#default_value'] = true; // Doesn't work.
    $form['expanded']['widget']['value']['#default_value'] = true; // Doesn't work either.

}
```

}

Attached below is an image to the form page in question.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To set a default value for the menu link entity use [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create/8.6.x):

```
use Drupal\menu_link_content\MenuLinkContentInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_create() for menu_link_content.
 */
function mymodule_menu_link_content_create(MenuLinkContentInterface $menu_link_content) {
  $menu_link_content->expanded->value = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "Show as expanded - always" module might be the answer?

https://www.drupal.org/project/show_as_expanded_always